# Tailwind CSS color opacity with a variable not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
const Home = () => {
    const variableOpacity = 0.85;
    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <div className={`h-8 bg-primary/[${variableOpacity}]`}>85%</div> 
           </main>
        </>
    );
};
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to make a Progress bar where I need the background color of a div to change as per a variable. I am using custom opacity like bg-primary/[0.85] and when I type this in the div it works but it doesn't work using a variable with same value as in the code sample. Actually, it works when the variable's value is 0.3 but it doesn't work for any other values.

**My Tailwind Config**
[image]

Comment: Can you post how your tailwind config is set up?

Comment: Try to [avoid](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth) construct class names dynamically

Comment: @Matt Please check it I have updated the post with the tailwind-config file

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Thank you for your comment. Looks like that is the problem here. But how do you think I can achieve my goal here i.e to change the background of the div dynamically. Should I do it with custom CSS or is there a way to achieve this with Tailwind

Comment: @Nirzal sorry not familiar with react, but I would change opacity directly with `style` property

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Thanks. I was thinking the same actually.

Answer (score 0):

Creating dynamic classes in tailwind won't work. That's because tailwind searches for your classes during build time and will only bundle the classes that it explicitly finds on source code.

The solution for what you want to do is to use the style props instead. Something like this:

```
const Home = () => {
    const variableOpacity = 0.85;
    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <div
                    className={'h-8'}
                    style={{backgroundColor:`rgba(51, 170, 51, ${variableOpacity})`}}
                >85%</div> 
            </main>
        </>
    );
};
```

Of course, as you have seen, you must specify the color in rgb notation (values in range 0-255 and opacity in range 0-1).